# How can I show a different UIImage in Iphone 4 vs Iphone 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

How can I show a different UIImage in Iphone 4 vs Iphone 5?

I want to show an image with different size on iphone 3,4 vs iphone 5. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

UIKit supports the specification of a `@2x` device modifier in order to select a retina-enabled version of an image through the `imageNamed` method.

This will allow to manage a non-retina and a retina version of the same image. Unfortunately, there is no provision for automatically handling an iPhone5-version of an image (except for Default.png). You will have to do that on your own.

Or, you can use [this category](https://gist.github.com/3782351) to be able to use a `-568h@2x` device extension for your iPhone5-specific image:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageNamedForDevice:(NSString*)name {

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
if (([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale) >= 1136.0f)
{
  //Check if is there a path extension or not
  if (name.pathExtension.length) {
    name = [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@", name.pathExtension]
                                           withString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-568h@2x.%@", name.pathExtension ] ];

  } else {
    name = [name stringByAppendingString:@"-568h@2x"];
  }

  //load the image e.g from disk or cache
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: name ]; 
  if (image) {
    //strange Bug in iOS, the image name have a "@2x" but the scale isn't 2.0f
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage: image.CGImage scale:2.0f orientation:image.imageOrientation];
  }

 }
}

return [UIImage imageNamed: name ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sideways way of doing it but also very quick:

```
int screenHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;
if (screenHeight<500) {
    //Show the UIImage for iPhone 4.
}
else {
    //Show the UIImage for iPhone 5.
}
```

Comment: The iPhone 4 screen is 480 high.  The iPhone 5 screen is 568.  You could pick any number between the two--481, 568, whatever--as long as they fell on either side of it.  500 just seemed the simplest.

Comment: it does not sound very professional, why don't you use instead the `if screenHeight<(arc4random()%88+480) { ... }` formula? it would not make sense either.